# GIT fixing duplicate commits pushed to remote

Tags: git, github

Not sure what exactly I did wrong, but I messed up something in my git repo and it looks something like this now:

```
master, origin/master   : C1
develop, origin/develop : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6     -> C7
feature, origin/feature : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -------> C6copy -> C7copy -> C8 ->...-> C50
```

What git commands should I run to get following state of my develop and master branches:

```
master, origin/master   : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -----> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50
develop, origin/develop : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -----> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50
```

I no longer intend to keep feature branch and I can delete it. But I want to merge all changes in development branch before doing so. Good thing is I am the only person pushing/pulling to/from this repository!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by ``C6copy`` and ``C7copy``? Are those cherry-picks of ``C6`` and ``C7`` done on top of ``C4``?

Comment: They are copies of C6 and C7

Comment: Can you not fast-forward merge feature onto develop?

Answer (score 1):

If C6copy and C7copy are actual copies of C6 and C7, you could do the following:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase develop
```

After these commands your feature should look like this if C6 and C7 were copies:

> feature : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50

Or like this if they were not:

> feature : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7 -> C6copy -> C7copy
>   -> C8 ->...-> C50

If they were not and you want to get rid of the copies you could interactive rebase instead to get rid of these two copied commits.
Once you reach the desired scenario in the feature branch, you could do:

```
git branch -f develop
git branch -f master
```

This will force the branches develop and master to your current position, which was C50, the last commit of feature. Then your repository would look like this:

> origin/master  : C1
>   master : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50
>   origin/develop : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7
>   develop : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50
>   origin/feature : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -------> C6copy -> C7copy -> C8 ->...-> C50
>   feature : C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> C5 -> C6 -> C7 -> C8 ->...-> C50

In this case, master would be 49 commits ahead of origin/master, and develop would be 43 commits ahead of origin/develop so you can just push them normally:

```
git checkout develop
git push origin develop
git checkout master
git push origin master
```

And finally all you need to do is delete feature if you want. feature would be 45 commits ahead and 46 behind origin/feature (because origin/feature is missing C5), you would need to force the deletion, as your branch isn't fully merged yet:

```
git branch -D feature
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try this and let you know. Also, I forgot to mention in my post. Notice that commit C5 was not part of from develop, origin/develop branches. Doesn't it impact the method you suggested ?

Comment: No, regardless C5 was part or not it shouldn't affect. As mentioned the only possible difference is if C6 and C7 are not copies then they (buy only they) will be duplicated

Comment: I am getting lot of merge conflicts for many commits. Too many. What about rebasing develop onto feature. Would it result in similar merge commits. Would it also rewrite history of commits in develop branch ?

Comment: You could rebase feature with develop, but the amount of conflicts is going to be the exact same. At the end you would have ...c4, c6copy, c7copy, c8, c9, ..., c50, c5, c6, c7. Then you would need to force push develop. I wouldn't recommend it. All the conflicts you re getting are the difference between (c5, c6 & c7) and (c6copy to c50)